# Zend select DB with no get column

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I have a problem with zend when I select data from DB. In my query I don't want select any column from table that I join with another table. I use array() in third parameter. But when I do this:

```
$sql = $db->select();
    $sql->from( "message", "message.message_id" )

        ->->join("network_users","message.network_id = network_users.network_id and message.user_id = network_users.user_id","network_users.network_id") //no get column
        ->join("users","message.user_id = users.user_id",array()) //no get column
        ->where( "message.network_id = :network_id" )
        ->where( "message.del_flg = 0" )
        ->where( "network_users.del_flg = 0" )
        ->where( "users.del_flg = 0" )
        ->order( "message.regist_date DESC" );

 $ary[':network_id']   = $network_id;
 $ret = $db->fetchAll($sql, $ary);

return empty($ret[0]["user_id"]) ? array():$ret;
```

I always get result is `array(0) {}`

When I get least one column in each table, it response correct result.

Any idea for my problem????

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It looks like the first `where` clause. You've passed in an parameter name 'network_id' and not a value. Do an echo of `$sql` to see what is being generated.

Comment: "message.user_id = network_users.user_id and message.user_id = network_users.user_id" why this ?

Comment: Hi, I have edited code above. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, problem is I used `return empty($ret[0]["user_id"]) ? array():$ret;` instead of `return empty($ret[0]["message_id"]) ? array():$ret;`.

That is reason I always receive `array(0) {}`.

Thanks for help. ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Use `null` instead of `array()`

So it would look like this:
`->join("users","message.user_id = users.user_id",null)`

Comment: Hi although I found out problem but I try to use null instead of array() it also work well.